# New acts like create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my create action, method new acts like create.

```
def create
  @page = Page.new(params[:page].merge(:user_id => current_user.id ))
  if @page.save
    flash[:notice] = t("success")
    redirect_to pages_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord creates new object in database while I'm using new with params. Page.new works fine in new action in my controller. What can be the reason? There is no overridden method new and no callbacks (before_save, before_create etc) in my model. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE - code from debugger

```
.../app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:48
@page = Page.new(params[:page].merge(:user_id => current_user.id ))
(rdb:25) @page
nil
(rdb:25) n
.../app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:49
if @page.save
(rdb:25) @page
#<Page id: 80 ... >
(rdb:25) Page.last
#<Page id: 80 ... >
(rdb:25) @page.save
false
```

Comment: dude page.save is triggering that thing :P

Comment: How do you know it creates new record in database while calling `Page.new`..the code after that saves it to database `@page.save`. `@page.save` will create new record in database. Is this what is happening? What do you want this code to do?

Comment: there are validations in my model, so if they fail, @page.save would return false and application will render action "new". Im sure, that Page.new(params[:page].merge(:user_id => current_user.id )) is saving record in database - found it with debugger

Comment: @zachar Thats not possible dude.. New can't "save" the object.

Comment: 'new' could theoretically save the model if there was some sort of call back that saved the object. Are there any call backs in the model?

Comment: I know how new should work, so that behaviour is surprising. Look at updated question - line by line from debugger. That is not matter of Page.new method - I think somewhere else there is some code, which may cause it. The problem is that I don't have any idea where could it be.

Comment: @Kevin Bedell, nope there is no callbacks in model, just some validations, translations, associations and workflow. Only line what I think can cause it is including ActiveModel::Dirty. Is that possible?

Comment: @zachar show us what your model has

Comment: Sorry, I'm not obligated to do that. It seems, that I must find solution by myself. I will post answer after got it. My post below contains everything I can tell.

Comment: Are you saying that if you comment out the _if @page.save_ that it saves to the database?

Comment: yes, its saved before performing @page.save - look at code from debugger. That is really confusing and works only with ugly fix.

Comment: Got it :) Some silly mistake in model. I will post answer for a while. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason (method in model which can change status in workflow):

```
def status=(state_name)
  states = [self.current_state.to_sym]
  possible_states.each {|t| states<< t[1]}
  unless state_name.blank?
    if states.include? state_name
    process_event! state_name
    end
  end
end
```

Ugly fix

```
def create
  @page = Page.new
  if @page.update_attributes(params[:page].merge(:user_id => current_user.id )) && @page.save
    flash[:notice] = t("success")
    redirect_to pages_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Mistake was quite silly and I'm not proud of my solution. Anyway, thanks for help:)

Answer (score 2):

Check my inline comments..

```
 def create
  @page = Page.new(params[:page].merge(:user_id => current_user.id )) # you trigger new thats fine..
  if @page.save # Notice here.. This line is triggering query on database.
    flash[:notice] = t("success")
    redirect_to pages_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: @page.save will return false if validation fails, so object won't be saved in database. If object is valid, code works. I suppose that is not proper solution for my problem.

Answer (score -1):

With an ActiveRecord class, `create = new + save`

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7edade337e968fb028b2b6abfa579120eb424039/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L40

Comment: That would be @page.create, not having a 'create' method in the controller. This answer seems incorrect.

Comment: Huh? The OP is talking about the AR model methods, not the controller methods.

Comment: Oh - I see now what you meant. I thought you were implying the OP should be using @page.create. I misunderstood.

Answer (score -1):

Your controller code is correct. This is how a 'create' controller method should work. The problem is not there.

Are you certain you're having two models created?

The `.new` method you're calling with the attributes creates an activerecord object in memory that's unsaved. The `.save` method saves it. At the end (assuming the data is valid) you should have a single object in memory.

If you have two objects created, then there is a problem. If you have only one, then it's as it should be.

Are you having a second object created by this controller method?

The process should be:

```
# when GET /student/new is called, this returns an empty object to display in the form
# for the user to see.
def new
  @page = Page.new
end

# When POST /page is called, the form params are passed in here.
def create
  # First, generate a new page object with the params passed in.
  @page = Page.new(params[:page].merge(:user_id => current_user.id ))
  # Now try save the object to persist it in the database.
  if @page.save
    flash[:notice] = t("success")
    redirect_to pages_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: If new was indeed creating an object, save could not create another one, it would just update it. @page will always point to the same object.

Comment: @Beerlington I understand. I understood the OP to be saying he was getting 2 objects saved -- one on the `new` and one on the `save`. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @Beerlington If you read my answer, it's 100% correct. I'm unsure why the downvote -- can you elaborate?

Comment: Bug occurs only when object is not valid - application redirects to form with validation errors, but object is already stored in database

Comment: Try replacing `.save` with `.save!` -- that should give you more information as to why the record has validation errors. The code as is looks OK. I think the problem is somewhere else.